# How to find the value on a chart scaled in decibels

Tags: sensor, atmega, atmel, light

I have the following chart

[image]

The blue line is the one I am interested in.

The question is how can I determine the value in LUX if I have the output voltage?

The problem is that I don't have any function to help me calculate this value.

**Later edit:**

If the light level from my room is indicated by 0.135V, I want to know how many LUX I have at that moment (the moment of conversion).

Comment: The #8ccff3 and the #427fbf lines both look like blue to me. Is your question how to create a function that is similar to this graph? Or just how to read/interpolate a log-log graph?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I updated my initial post. Any method that provides the perfect result is ok. I just need to know the value at that moment for my read voltage.

Answer (score 5):

This may help you read the value off the graph, or read values to curve-fit.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't this motivated, but I think that's exactly what he was looking for, haha.

Comment: How did you put those grid lines on the image?

Comment: Photoshop. Screen capture your image and a log-log graph image, put them on separate layers, make the graph layer suitably transparent, Ctrl-T (free transform) the graph layer and drag it so the major divisions coincide. Free image manipulation prog Gimp should work too- layers + scale tool.

Answer (score 3):

What you have there is a log-log plot. It uses a logarithmic scale rather than linear on both x and y axes. To get your value you can simply just extrapolate. However, if you are not familiar with plots like these it can be tricky. For example, 45 or 50 are not dead center between 10 and 100. In fact, the center is right around 30. This picture from here [Logarithmic Scale - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale) shows how the spacing is arranged on a log plot.

[image: log scale]

It's also worth familiarizing yourself with how decibels work. For power quantities, the equation is:

\$ L_\mathrm{dB} = 10 \log_{10} \bigg(\frac{P_1}{P_0}\bigg) \$

For quantities that aren't power, like volts or amps or whatever else isn't power, the equation is

\$ G_\mathrm{dB} = 20 \log_{10} \bigg(\frac{A_1}{A_0}\bigg) \$

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) also appears to be a good source for this particular topic.